# combine three functions using r

Tags: r, matrix

hello i created the following functions that test reliability. however i want to combine them into one function like :reliability<-function(x)in order for them to give me a 1-0 matris showing each answer for each function with in "reliability". because each has been giving me the answer on its own. if any ideas help.

```
splithalf1<- function( data ) {   

      n<-ncol(data)
      tek<-data[ , seq(1,n , 2)]
     cift<-data[ , seq(2 ,n , 2)]
      top_single<-rowSums(single)
      top_double<-rowSums(double)
      kor<-cor(top_single,top_double)
       r<-2*kor / (1+kor)
       return(r)
}

cr.alpha2<- function(x) {
       n<-ncol(x)
      kov<-cov(x)
      kov1<-as.vector(kov)
      kov2<-unique (kov1)
      kov3<- kov2[-1]
      kov4<-sum(kov3)/length(kov3)
      pay<- n*kov4
      payd<- (1 + (n-1)*kov4)
       alpha<-pay/payd
       return(alpha)
}

kr20<-function(x) {
   n<-ncol(x)
  pq<-function(x) { 
     p<-mean(x) 
     q<-1-p
     res<-p*q 
     return (res)
  }
   pay<- sum(apply(x,2,pq))
   top<-rowSums(x)
   payda<-var(top)
   result<- n /(n-1)* (1-(pay/payda))
   return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack is not a coding service! As a teaching service to you, however, I will suggest several things which is probably the intent of your teacher in the first place!

1. Study up on fundamental R. There are innumerable (well numerable but innumerable for all practical individual purposes) resources for free on the net. One good (IMO), free, intro-to-journeyman-level book is *R for Data Science* which can be accessed here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/
2. check out assigning function return values to vars.
3. check out the c() and matrix() functions.